# Was linseed (flaxseed) oil in common use in time of the Mishna/Gemara?

Tags: talmud-gemara, food, technology, science

Go to any location 200+ years old in America, and they'll tell you all about the value of linseed (flax seed) for paint. Which makes me wonder, was it a "thing" in the time of the Talmud? Obviously we hear all about linen for clothing, but was its seed as a food (or its oil for paint, or burning, or treating wood), ever discussed?

Comment: Does the famous story of Rabbi Chiya in Kesubos 103b count? Where he brought flax seed, sowed it and weaved nets  from its plants in order to catch the deer to provide meat for the yesomim and use the skins to make scrolls with which to teach the kids. https://www.sefaria.org/Ketubot.103b.19?ven=Daf_Shevui&lang=bi

Comment: @Dov it's a great story and thanks for bringing it! We all know that the classical sources valued the plant for its fibers, but this story is just about using its seed to grow fibers. I was  looking for some other use for the seeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nedarim 49a discusses the use of flaxseed for food:

> לוּלִיבָּא דְכִיתָּנָא בְּכוּתָּחָא
>
> The innards of flaxseeds are best eaten with *kutecha*